# Binding checkbox in Thymeleaf + Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Spring MVC app is based on Spring boot 1.2.8, Thymeleaf, Hibernate and Hateos. I've an entity "Market" with a field "enabled" of type Boolean.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "market")
public class Market {
.....
private Boolean enabled;
....
public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Code in controller for "/create"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView create() {
    return new ModelAndView("market/create")
            .addObject("list", linkTo(methodOn(MarketController.class).list())
                    .withRel("List"))
            .addObject("market", new Market())
            .addObject("postLink",
                    linkTo(methodOn(MarketController.class).save(null, null, null, null))
                            .withRel("Save"));
}
```

Template "market/create", ref. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#checkbox-fields

```
    <form th:action="${postLink.href}" th:object="${market}" method="post">
        ....
        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="${#ids.next('enabled')}" th:text="#{market.enabled}">Enabled</label>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{enabled}" />
        </div>
        ....
    </form>
```

When opening /markets/create in the browser, getting the following exception on the line with the checkbox

```
Cause: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException Attribute "value" is required in "input(checkbox)" tags when binding to non-boolean values
```

Why is Thymeleaf considering the field "enabled" as non-boolean type? I have tried all my best to figure out the cause but in vain. Plz give some hints to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Controller**

```java
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    private String index(DemoDto demoDto){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    private String receiveValues(DemoDto demoDto) {
        System.out.println(demoDto);
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**DTO**

```java
public class DemoDto {
    private String name;
    private boolean global;

    //getter setter for name

    public boolean isGlobal() {
        return global;
    }
    public void setGlobal(boolean global) {
        this.global = global;
    }

    //toString()
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/}" th:method="post" th:object="${demoDto}">
        <label>Enter Name:</label> 
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" name="name"> 
        <br/>
        <label>Global</label>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="${demoDto.global}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

Here most important is how you define `th:field="${demoDto.global}"`. Both `$` as well as object name `demoDto` are required here.

Generated html code will be.

```html
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <label>Enter Name:</label> 
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""> 
        <br/>
        <label>Global</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="global1" name="global" value="true"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="_global" value="on"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

When submitted from ui received:

```
DemoDto [name=Dev, global=true]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've eventually found simple and understandable example how to implement form with checkbox. May I ask you to add example wih multiple checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

In any case, the attribute `value`is mandatory.

Try something like this : `<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{enabled}" value="true" />`. The `enabled` field should be setted by `true` when you checked the input; `null`otherwise.

Comment: Thanks David, I tried with "value" earlier but its getting ignored when saved in DB . As far as I understand there's no need to add "value" in forms, backed by spring beans, its done by thymeleaf. plz correct me if I'm wrong. Example. https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm/blob/2.1-master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/seedstartermng.html, look for <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{covered}" />

Comment: You are right, sorry I made a mistake, the attribute `enabled` should be initialized if you remove the `value`attribute.

Comment: yeah, tried it too. Made "private Boolean enabled = Boolean.FALSE" in the entity class, but thymeleaf is not considering it as a "boolean" and continues to throw the exception. I'm looking at the sample https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm/blob/2.1-master/src/main/java/thymeleafexamples/stsm/business/entities/SeedStarter.java, it has a field "covered" of type Boolean.

Comment: Is there a `value` attribute in the generated HTML with a non-null value ? According to the source code, this exception is triggered when value is null in the post process.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your attribute something other than 'enabled', perhaps 'marketEnabled'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{enabled}" value="true" />
```

When we checked the checkbox input, it set the value of that checkbox "true".
This work perfectly fine in my case.